# python --version shows old version

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, path, version

I'm using Windows, and in my path I have:

```
C:\Users\Ant_P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\
C:\Users\Ant_P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\
```

When I type `python3 --version`, it still shows me `3.10.8`.

I deleted the old python folder, but it still exists. I've tried looking online, but I'm not seeing how to fix this. I thought I just had to set my path, but apparently there is something else going on. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

When you first install, In setup you have to set **Add python.exe to PATH** and choose **Customize installation** then set **Install Python for all users**.

I had the same problem and reinstalling worked (with python 3.12.0)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU2Egc3Zx3Q

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows and you have installed Python 3.11, you should type `python --version` instead of `python3 --version`.

Alternatively, you can try running `py --version` to see which version of Python is currently being used by your system.

If you have set your `PATH` correctly and it still shows the wrong version of Python, you can try restarting your command prompt or shell to see if the changes take effect.

Comment: I've tried all of those things already and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed two python versions. I had same problem and It would said I am using lower python version. also I am using windows 11.

well first try to restart and it may solve the problem.
If it didnt solve it, go to your environment variables and delete the lower version path. In my case I had used "move down" button, so I moved lower version path under newer one then I restarted. It was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Environment Variables. Edit PATH. If you have multiple paths there for multiple python versions, make sure the one you would like to be used by default is above PATH for other versions.

Keep check of hierarchy of PATH in both User Variables and System Variables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).